# Flutter create command was unsuccessful error

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm creating a new `flutter` project in `Android studio`. I give the project a name and choose `Flutter` application. I then clicked finish and then nothing happened.
Android studio says that

```
"Flutter create command was unsuccessful"
```

When I navigate to command directory using file explorer, a new folder is created with the project name I've given but it is empty.

Please help.

Comment: What was the name? Did you try in a terminal window as well? What is the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: It found one issue.  [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\[user-name]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    X Android license status unknown.

Comment: I resolved it by updating SDK manager but still unable to create flutter project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solution to this problem now.
After running `flutter doctor --android-licenses` I got to know that I need to update my `sdkManager`.

Then I went to that directory using

```
cd C:\Users\[user-name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
```

and run `sdkmanager --update`

Then I restarted the `Android Studio` and tried creating flutter project.

It worked.

Answer (score 10):

A simple Android Studio restart did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

check your FLUTTER SDK path of the project (android studio: file -> settings -> Language & framework -> flutter -> flutter sdk path) . Or execute flutter doctor command in flutter consol.(This worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

please install all the dependencies that flutter wants
Operating Systems: Linux (64-bit)
Disk Space: 600 MB (does not include disk space for IDE/tools).
Tools: Flutter depends on these command-line tools being available in your environment.
*bash
*curl
*file
*git 2.x
*mkdir
*rm
*unzip
*which
*xz-utils
*zip
Shared libraries: Flutter *test command depends on this library being available in your environment.
libGLU.so.1 - provided by mesa packages such as libglu1-mesa on Ubuntu/Debian and mesa-libGLU on Fedora

Comment: sudo apt install curl
sudo apt install git
sudo apt install xz-utils

Answer (score 0):

Look at Flutter sdk path while Creating the Project.

```
$ C:\flutter
```

If your Flutter SDK is updated and the path is right you will get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your Flutter SDK path.
2. Check the package name. It must be in lower case.
3. Restart your IDE and check again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution for it:

1. Check all the SDK paths (Flutter and Android Studio)
2. run `flutter doctor` in command prompt/terminal
3. run  `flutter doctor --android-licenses` in terminal to update the SDK manager

`cd C:\Users\[user-name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin`
and run `sdkmanager --update`

4. important point-- make sure your flutter and git folder should be in C drive... Directly in the C drive, not inside any folder of the C drive.

Then try to create a project in Flutter in Android Studio

Make sure about the 4th point, it's very important.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downloading the latest version of Flutter SDK.

I wanted to create a new Flutter project by clicking File->New->New Flutter project.
But every time it showed

> "Flutter create command was unsuccessful"
> "Run flutter doctor."

My flutter doctor did not find any issues. Then I have downloaded the latest version of Flutter SDK, at the time of writing the version is

"flutter_windows_3.13.1-stable".

I downloaded and replaced all folders of my Flutter SDK with it.