# Flutter create unsuccessful

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and dart and learning how this thing works. The problem is I cannot get passed the first stage.

I cant seem to create the project.

I get two notification after hitting the finish button on the project creation screen.

> Flutter create command was not successful.
>
> Exception: Cannot run program "C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat" (in
> directory "C:\Users\Chris\AndroidStudioProjects"): CreateProcess
> error=5, Access is denied

Anyone out there can help me?
P.S: I also referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197922/flutter-create-command-was-unsuccessful-error), but never understood.

Comment: Did you mange to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Just locate your `flutter.bat` file, right click -> properties -> security tab -> edit -> select your user -> grant full control -> ok ok save save.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Happy coding!

Comment: I did that but didn't solved the problem, any help ?