# flutter create command was unsuccessful in andorid studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I succeeded in using

```
flutter create myapp
```

but when I am creating a new flutter project in Android Studio, it always says:

> Flutter create command was unsuccessful

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please share some code and logs

Comment: Did you check this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52197922/5180017)? And also do check-out this Github [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/1019)

Comment: I've had a bunch of issues with Android Studio, but not specifically to Flutter (mainly Gradle), where the command line seems to fix stuff Android Studio says isn't working... You could always create it from the command line and open using Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Can you please review your all setup in android studio for flutter

You can just do a `flutter create my_project_name` in the terminal (Make sure flutter path is set)

**Steps Create the app**

- Select File > New Flutter Project.
- Select Flutter application as the project type, and press Next.
- Make sure that the Flutter SDK Path text field specifies the location of the SDK. Install the SDK if you haven’t yet done so.
- Enter a project name (for example, myapp), and press Next.
- Click Finish.
- Wait for Android Studio to install the SDK, and create the project.

Check bellow links for more reference:

https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/editor?tab=androidstudio

then

https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/android-studio

Then create app

https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/test-drive?tab=androidstudio